# Can't get state in return area

Tags: reactjs, state, textfield, material-ui

I have state that i set in componentDidMount. i can get the state value in render, but when i want to get in return area the state value is empty. is there anything wrong in my code?

Here is how i set my state :

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            item: [],
            nama: '',
            kategori: '',
        }
    }

    loadAsesmen = () => {
        fetch("http://localhost/assessment-app/adminpg/api/v1/Proses_asesmen/do_asesmen/?id="+localStorage.getItem('idasesmen'), {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
        })
        .then(posts => {
            return posts.json();
        }).then(data => {
            let item = data.posts.map((itm) => {
                return(
                    <div key={itm.prosesasesmen_id}>
                        <h3>{itm.soal}</h3>
                        <br />
                        <RadioButtonGroup name="opsJawaban" defaultSelected="not_light">
                            <RadioButton value="1" label="Ya" style={styles.radioButton} /> 
                            <RadioButton value="0" label="Tidak" style={styles.radioButton} />
                        </RadioButtonGroup>
                    </div>
                )
            });
            this.setState({item: item, nama: data.posts[0].nama, kategori: data.posts[0].kategori});
            //localStorage.setItem('nama', data.posts[0].nama);
            //localStorage.setItem('kategori', data.posts[0].kategori);
            //console.log("State", this.state.item);
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadAsesmen();
    }
```

And here is code where i try to get the state :

```
    render () {
        const settings = {
            dots: false,
            infinite: false,
            speed: 500,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            swipeToSlide: false,
            swipe: false,
            nextArrow: <SampleNextArrow />,
            prevArrow: <SamplePrevArrow />
        };

        // const csrNama = localStorage.getItem('nama');
        // const csrKategori = localStorage.getItem('kategori');
        const query = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search);
        localStorage.setItem('idasesmen', query.get('id'));
        console.log(this.state.nama);

        return (
            <div>
            <Card>
                <CardText>
                    <TextField
                      disabled={true}
                      hintText="Nama"
                      defaultValue={this.state.nama}
                      floatingLabelText="Nama"
                    />
                    <br />
                    <TextField
                      disabled={true}
                      hintText="Kategori"
                      defaultValue={csrKategori}
                      floatingLabelText="Kategori"
                    />
```

The console log can get value of this.state.nama but the TextField object can't.
Is there something that i miss?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kl6oq.png)

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: change it to value={this.state.nama}

Comment: *facepalm*. I never thought reactjs would make me like an idiot. Thank you so much, you saved my life =))

Comment: its actually a material-ui component. are you familiar with their documentation ? its great http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field  just make sure you're viewing the right version.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <TextField
    disabled={true}
    hintText="Nama"
    defaultValue={this.state.nama}
    floatingLabelText="Nama"
 />
```

Because your state starts with undefined **defaultValue** is initialized with `''`. Updating the defaultValue after it already has a value won't do anything which is why updating this to **value** will work. (This will make it a controlled input so you will need to add an onChange if you plan to allow the user to edit the value)

An alternative if you do want to keep defaultValue is to make it not render the **TextField** until you **finish loading** your async function